# Liclipse PyDev unittests WITHOUT Django

Tags: unit-testing, pydev, python-unittest

I've created a completely empty PyDev project (NOT "PyDev Django", just "PyDev"), with this single file in it:

```
import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def testName(self):
        print "hello world"
```

And when I either right-click on the file and select "Run As"->"Python unit test", or press CTRL+F9 and click on "testName", I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 1.2.0\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251617\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 1.2.0\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251617\pysrc\runfiles.py", line 26, in main
    import pydev_runfiles
  File "C:\Program Files\Brainwy\LiClipse 1.2.0\plugins\org.python.pydev_3.8.0.201409251617\pysrc\pydev_runfiles.py", line 5, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

If I put this in the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

and execute it using "Run As"->"Python Run", it works fine, but of course it's inconvenient in case there are many tests in the file.

How do I get PyDev to execute the unit tests without Django?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by updating LiClipse from 1.2.0 to 1.4.0 :)